# Save multiple child on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, parent-child

I'm having some trouble on the concept of saving multiple child for what I need on MVC 5. The entity comes from a currency pair graph on a daily basis that would be the parent. And what I need its to create the parent, lets say Euro/Dollar and then assign important levels that can  be one, two, or ten. So I know I could create the parent and then in other step create the childs but its not very "friendly" as it has to be done for lots of currency pairs and everyday. I wonder if theres a way to do this all in a single page. I don't know if I'm being clear with what I want, but as a concept I think it is like adding tags to a blog, you create the "blog article" and add tags all at same page but you don't know how many tags the article will have.

This are my models

```
public class Pair
{
    public int pairID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Levels> Levels { get; set; }
}

public class Levels
{
    public int levelID { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public int pairID { get; set; }
    public virtual Pair Pair { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can save parent child records from single page for sure, but I couldn't understand your requirement clearly.

Comment: Well the question is how. Like how to assign the parent ID to the childs if its been created with same button.

Comment: Some examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of for achieving what you want:

- **If the number of child records that you want is limited then you can achieve this without the use of any `JavaScript`.**

### Example:

This example will only allow you to add 5 `Levels` per `Pair`. If you want you can just change the following code to increase the number of `Levels`

```
Levels = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new Levels()).ToList();
```

**Model**

```
public class Pair
{
    public Pair()
    {
        Levels = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new Levels()).ToList();
    }  
    ....
}

public class Levels
{
    ....
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExampleParentChild()
{
    return View(new Pair());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExampleParentChild(Pair pair)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Pairs.Add(pair);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(pair);
}
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.Date)
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Date)

    @foreach(var item in Model.Levels)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(m=> item.Value)
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> item.Value)

        @Html.LabelFor(m=> item.comment)
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> item.comment)
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

- **If you want the number of child records to be dynamic then you will have to use `JavaScript` to be able to add more `input` elements to the page on the run. You can either use `jQuery` or `AngularJS`. I am providing you an example with the use of `AngularJS` and `WEB API`, the reason I am providing you an example with `AngularJs` is that you asked to do it in a single page and everyone uses `AngularJS` nowadays for SPAs.**

### Example:

**AngularController**

```
angular.module('Pair', [])
    .controller('PairController', PairController);
function AccountController($http) {
    vm.Pair = {};
    vm.Pair.Levels = []
    vm.addLevel = function(){
        if (vm.Pair.Levels)
        {
            vm.Pair.Levels.push({});
        }
    };
    vm.savePair = function () {
        $http.post('/api/PairsApi/', vm.Pair).success(function (data) {
            vm.Pair = {};
        }).error(function (data) {
            // code for error
        });
    };
};
```

**WEBAPI**

```
[Route("api/PairApi/{id?}", Name = "api_PairApi")]
public class PairLedgersApiController : ApiBaseController 
{
    DbContext _db = new DbContext();
    public IHttpActionResult PostPairLedger(Pair pair)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _db.Pairs.Add(pair);
        _db.Save();

        return CreatedAtRoute("api_PairApi", new { id = pair.Id }, Pair);
    }
.....
}
```

**View**

```
<div data-ng-app="Pair" data-ng-controller="PairController as vm">
    <form name="PairForm" ng-submit="vm.savePair()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-body">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="pairName" ng-model="vm.Pair.name " class="form-control"/>

            <label>Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="pairDate" ng-model="vm.Pair.Date" value="{{vm.Pair.Date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" class="form-control"/>

            <div ng-repeat="level in vm.Pair.Levels">
                <label>Value</label>
                <input type="text" name="levelValue" ng-model="level.value" class="form-control"/>

                <label>Comment</label>
                <input type="text" name="levelComment" ng-model="level.comment" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn blue" />
            <button ng-click="vm.addLevel();" class="btn blue">
                Add Level
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you are new to `AngularJS`, you can refer to the following links for using it with `ASP .NET MVC`:

[Build a Single Page Application (SPA) with ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-(spa)-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs)

[CRUD with SPA, ASP.NET Web API and Angular.js](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832288/CRUD-with-SPA-ASP-NET-Web-API-and-Angular-js)

Answer (score -1):

```
public long Save(INVStoreTrans model, int userId, string pageUrl)
    {
        long CurrentTransactionID = 0;

        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {

                using (_context)
                {
                    var GetTransactionNo = DalCommon.GetPreDefineNextCodeByUrl(pageUrl);

                    if (GetTransactionNo != null)
                    {
                        #region New_Transaction_Insert

                        INV_StoreTrans objIssue = new INV_StoreTrans();

                        objIssue.TransactionNo = GetTransactionNo;
                        objIssue.TransactionDate = DalCommon.SetDate(model.TransactionDate);
                        objIssue.TransactionCategory = "ISU";
                        objIssue.TransactionType = "STI";
                        objIssue.TransactionFrom = model.IssueFrom;
                        objIssue.TransactionTo = model.IssueTo;

                        objIssue.TransactionStatus = "TRI";


                        objIssue.RecordStatus = "NCF";
                        objIssue.SetBy = userId;
                        objIssue.SetOn = DateTime.Now;

                        _context.INV_StoreTrans.Add(objIssue);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                        CurrentTransactionID = objIssue.TransactionID;
                        #endregion

                        #region Item Insert
                        if (model.TransactionItemList != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item in model.TransactionItemList)
                            {
                                INV_StoreTransItem objItem = new INV_StoreTransItem();

                                objItem.TransactionID = CurrentTransactionID;

                                objItem.ItemID = item.ItemID;
                                objItem.SupplierID = item.SupplierID;

                                objItem.TransactionQty = item.IssueQty;

                                objItem.TransactionUnit = DalCommon.GetUnitCode(item.IssueUnitName);


                                objItem.PackSize = DalCommon.GetSizeCode(item.IssuePackSizeName);
                                objItem.SizeUnit = DalCommon.GetUnitCode(item.IssueSizeUnitName);


                                objItem.PackQty = item.IssuePackQty;
                                //objItem.ItemSource = DalCommon.ReturnItemSource(item.ItemSource);
                                objItem.SetOn = DateTime.Now;
                                objItem.SetBy = userId;

                                _context.INV_StoreTransItem.Add(objItem);
                                //_context.SaveChanges();
                            }

                        }
                        #endregion
                    }
                    _context.SaveChanges();

                }
                transaction.Complete();
            }
            return CurrentTransactionID;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```